# Unexpected child "familiy" found under "fonts". en Flutter

Tags: flutter

Estoy intetando colocar fuentes personalizadas y creo que estoy identando bien, según lo que veo en un video y la documentación de Flutter, aquí está lo que coloco:

```
fonts:
  - family: OpenSans
    fonts:
      - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
      - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
        weight: 700
  - familiy: Quicksand
    fonts:
      - asset: assets/fonts/QuickSand-Regular.ttf
      - asset: assets/fonts/QuickSand-Bold.ttf
        weight: 700
```

Y este es el error que aparece:

```
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Unexpected child "familiy" found under "fonts".
Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at E:\PROYECTOS\Movil\Flutter-projects\EXPENSES_PLANNING\pubspec.yaml
exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estaba mal escrito `family` en la segunda fuente.

Answer (score 1):

Verifica los espacios o identación del archivo pubspec.yaml, puedes guiarte de este enlace https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts

Comment: Si bien este elance puede contener información útil, es mejor añadir las partes más importantes que respondan la pregunta y exponer el enlace como referencia